# How to show all x86 control registers when debugging the Linux kernel in GDB through QEMU?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

I am curious why gdb does not show control registers for x86. I have been using gdb with qemu to debug some kernel stuff. I get register values using info registers and info all-registers.

However, I cant get cr3 and cr2.(In general CRs). Is there any way to get them. If not then why are not they provided.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using qemu, you can get all registers states (even control ones) by issuing theses two commands in the shell you start qemu:

- ctrl-a c  (to switch to qemu command interface)
- info registers (to get registers states)

Comment: This does not include the majority of ARM control registers unfortunately, e.g. QEMU 4.0.0 does not show `SCTLR_EL1.nTWE`.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

You could check the values of the control registers from gdb. The issue is that your program must be running in real mode (mostly bootloaders have a part that runs on real-mode this days).

UPDATE FROM @Mahouk:

Since me and @Majouk have the same number of votes on this thread, you should definitely check out his answer and try getting the register values from qemu.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I had the same issue and it seems that gdb doesn't have that option unfortunately.
I am not sure why they are not provided but I can suggest to you an alternative.

You could switch to Bochs from Qemu. Yes, it might be a bit quirky or slower but
it has a very good internal debugger. The command to see the control registers with
bochs is `creg`.

For more information, you can reference Boch's documentation [here](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html).

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

`info registers` in QEMU 4.0.0 did show CR registers to me, likely due to a QEMU update, since it is QEMU sends an XML describing which registers it will show to GDB. I see:

```
cr0            0x80050033       [ PG AM WP NE ET MP PE ]
cr2            0x6a8d18 6982936
cr3            0xe0bc000        [ PDBR=7 PCID=0 ]
cr4            0x7406f0 [ PKE SMAP SMEP OSXSAVE OSXMMEXCPT OSFXSR PGE MCE PAE PSE ]
cr8            0x0      0
```

or I can also get individual ones with:

```
i r cr0
i r cr2
i r cr3
```

Tested with [this exact setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/ed5fa984c6226f81cb1a07f980d319ee9ee88e00#gdb-step-debug-kernel-boot).